# How to prevent same modal from loading multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

- This is a rails application
- Modal will be displayed by clicking on a link
- The link will trigger an action in rails controller which will show
  the modal
- When double clicked on this link , the modal appears multiple times
  for each click until modal covers the page.
- How to prevent double action trigger through link and display only
  one modal?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and rewrite your question (for example, show the relevant code..)

Comment: Please paste the code because we cannot suggest anything without the code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on tag jquery in question. I assume you got something like this

```
$("#open-modal").on("click", function(){
    #ajax request
});
```

you should have some "flag" that will toggle between states "open", "closed" and based on it, it should close modal or send ajax.

```
flag = {};
flag.is_open = false;
$("#open-modal").on("click", function(){
   if(!flag.is_open){ // so at first click result is true
      #ajax request
      #modal creation
      flag.is_open = true; // when user click second time you wont send ajax 
   }
});

 // and when u close

$("#close-modal").on("click", function(){
   if(flag.is_open){ // it is open
      #modal-destruction
      flag.is_open = false; 
   }
});
```

but you really should give us a piece of code so we could suggest something based on your work

Comment: But Link has a path to rails controller action. The action fetches for data from database that is to be shown on the modal. Then that controller action renders a javascript erb file in which the code to show modal is written.

Comment: then i guess I would go for session to keep information if modal is open
`session[:modal] = true // false if closed`. But I belive there is better solution. I have never render javascript from rails, I would use javascript to send request and get json back from rails controller then put data in modal.

Comment: I did'nt understand the solution you mentioned. @hodiecode

Comment: @AbhijithR
if you will give more code then we will try to find solution

Comment: from html to rails controller. The process of creating modal and showing it to the user